# Separate coconut oil using microwave

Tags: oil, coconut, thai-cuisine

I am cooking thai curry and wondering if I can seperate coconut oil using microwave?

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/14867/67

Comment: Also, a question on how to do the opposite: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19456/how-do-i-prevent-coconut-milk-from-separating-in-thai-curry/